# Does using the assignment operator of the STL containers in my assignment operator leak memory?

Tags: c++, stl

I have the following constructors, destructor, and assignment operator in one of my classes. I am wondering if it leaks memory.

```
MenuItem::MenuItem() {
  menu_items = new vector<MenuItem>;
}

MenuItem::MenuItem(const MenuItem &other) {
  menu_items = new vector<MenuItem>(*other.menu_items);
}

MenuItem::~MenuItem() {
  menu_items->erase(menu_items->begin(), menu_items->end());
  delete menu_items;
}

MenuItem & MenuItem::operator= (const MenuItem &other) {
  *menu_items = *other.menu_items;
  return *this;
}
```

My main concern is the assignment operator. I looked at some documentation and found this: `The container preserves its current allocator, which is used to allocate storage in case of reallocation. Any elements held in the container before the call are either assigned to or destroyed.` To me this means that my assignment is safe from memory leaks, but I've misinterpretted the documentation before. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why allocate the vector on the heap to begin with?

Comment: It looks like it doesn't leak; but to be sure, why not get rid of the pointless dynamic allocation? (Also, there's no point erasing the contents of a container before destroying it.)

Comment: Also, the `erase` before `delete` is unnecessary.

Comment: To answer your question, no. The destuctor for each Menu Item in the vector is called when it goes out of scope (i.e. is removed from the vector). But yeah. Don't allocate the vector on the heap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code looks good, but don't dynamically allocate the `vector`. A `vector` dynamically allocates its elements anyway, so there's little use of allocating the container itself. If you make the `vector` a data member your code reduces to:

```
struct MenuItem
{
  std::vector<MenuItem> menu_items;
};
```

Everything else will be implicitly generated by the compiler. If you really have a valid reason for `new`ing the `vector`, the only changes I recommend are using constructor initializer lists for initialization and not calling `vector::erase` in the destructor because it is unnecessary.

```
MenuItem::MenuItem() 
: menu_items(new vector<MenuItem>())
{}

MenuItem::MenuItem(const MenuItem &other)
: menu_items(new vector<MenuItem>(*other.menu_items))
{}

MenuItem::~MenuItem() 
{
  delete menu_items;
}
```

Comment: `: menu_items(new vector<MenuItem>(*other.menu_items))` is a bit of a trap for exception handling. In general, however, using the initialization list is a good practice. Probably, the best solution would be `: menu_items(new vector<MenuItem>(*other.menu_items.size()))` and then perform the copy in the body

Answer (score 2):

There is no memory leak in your program because of the assignment operator. However, it feels very strange to allocate the vector on the heap, do you have any reason for doing so?

In reality, there could be a memory leak if the allocator of the contained object throws an exception. Let me explain

1. you call the copy constructor
2. it tries to instantiate a new vector calling `new`; this could throw an exception and this would be fine, no problem at all
3. the call to operator `new` succedes, but the allocator of the contained object throws an exception; you don't catch the exception in the constructor, the constructor throws and no destructor is called -> memory leak as for the (possibly not empty) vector you allocated.

If you are using C++11 you can solve the issue by delegating to the default constructor from within the copy constructor, as in:

```
MenuItem::MenuItem(const MenuItem &other) : MenuItem(){
  *menu_items = *other.menu_items;
}
```

If you do so, when you reach the assignment of `*menu_items` the object is fully constructed (by `: MenuItem()`, so to say) and if this throws the destructor gets called and `delete menu_items` gets executed.

If you are not using C++11

```
MenuItem::MenuItem(const MenuItem &other) : menu_items(NULL) {
  try{ menu_items = new vector<MenuItem>(*other.menu_items); }
  catch(...){delete menu_items;}
}
```

which is probably a betters solution anyway.

What you cite from the documentation is of no concern in this context, it means that the container will use the same function to allocate the objects it contains.

Answer (score 0):

That looks fine, in the sense of having no memory errors: you're deleting the vector on destruction (although there's no need to erase the contents first), and implementing copy semantics so that each vector is owned by exactly one object. The vector also has correct copy semantics (since otherwise it would be to dangerous to use), so your assignment operator is correct.

However, there's no point in dynamically allocating the `vector` at all. Why not make it a member variable? Then you can simplify all that code to the following: